# rails_admin add custom controller in namespace admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes, rails-admin

I'm heaving a problem - in my app i'm using rails_admin and want to add a custom controller to 'admin' namespace.

i create a custom controller `Admin::CustomController`
Then i create a link to it in `rails_admin.config`

```
  config.navigation_static_links = {
      'Custom Controller' => '/admin/custom'
  }
```

i get a warning when i try to access this link via browser

```
Model 'Custom' could not be found
```

How can fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem relative to the `Model 'Custom' could not be found`, you have to create a routes for your custom controller and define it before the rails_admin routes mount point.

For instance in your routes.rb:

```
# must be before rails_admin
namespace :admin do
  resource :custom
end

mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
```